# Remove sorting in meteor project from mongo

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am working on my first project using Meteor, and am having some difficulty with sorting.

I have a select element where user choose option that are then displayed in a list. But I do not know how to remove sorting and show all values.

I tried:

*admin.html*

```
<select name="select">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="bad">Bad</option>
    <option value="sad">Sad</option>
    <option value="good">Good</option>
    <option value="best">Best</option>
</select>
```

*admin.js*

```
Template.adminLayout.events({
    "change select": function (event) {
        // Prevent default browser form submit
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get value from select element
        const listEmo = $( event.target ).val();
        console.log(listEmo);

        if(listEmo == "all") {
            Session.set("HeardFrom", null);
        } else {
            Session.set("HeardFrom", listEmo);
        }

    }
});
```

*feed.js*

```
Template.feed.helpers({
    feedbacks() {
        return FeedbacksList.find({ feedback: Session.get("HeardFrom") });
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

figured out

```
if (listEmo == "all") {
    const emoList = {};
    Session.set("HeardFrom", emoList);
} else {
    const emoList = {feedback : listEmo};
    Session.set("HeardFrom", emoList);
}
```